# Oracle/SQL - Cursor gives Not Enough Memory for CONNECT BY operation

Tags: sql, oracle

When I create a cursor `cur` as follows -

```
CURSOR cur IS SELECT Rownum r FROM dual WHERE mod(rownum,2)=1 CONNECT BY rownum <15;
```

It gives me an error `ORA-30009: Not enough memory for CONNECT BY operation`.

I tried reducing the limit to even 3, but it didn't work.

It might be of help to know that I'm running a loop using this cursor as-

```
FOR cur_inst IN cur
    LOOP
        dbms_output.put_line(cur_inst.r);
    END LOOP;
```

The loop runs one time and prints `1`. However the above error is thrown after the first iteration.

Also, if I remove the `WHERE` clause, the query is executed correctly as-

[image: QUERY OUTPUT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply your filtering logic after *connecting* the rows! otherwise, it would mess up the connection.

```
CURSOR cur IS
select r  from
(SELECT Rownum r FROM dual CONNECT BY rownum <15
 )
 where mod(r,2)=1
```